# Powershell to pull vaules from a excel spreed sheet

Tags: excel, powershell

I was wondering if it is possible to use PowerShell to pull information from a spreadsheet and update an internal site. The thing I can't figure out is how to tell PowerShell to go get the information from this spreadsheet to search update ect?

Looking around I can't seem to find much or must be looking in the wrong location.

This is the search code at the moment, I can manually put a value in and will search but would like it to pull from a spreadsheet.

```
$serchLink = $ie.document.getElementById("quicksearchbox").Value = 11444
```

I want the .vaule = "pull this data from a spreadsheet"

Thank you for your help if possible.

Comment: You can export your spreadsheet as CSV and then use [Import-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Get-Content` and `Import-Csv` to retrieve data from a file. If you want specific content you can look through the sheet and get what you need.

```
$getlist = Get-Content "C:\Users\path\test.txt"
```

And then you can select the data you want like this.

```
foreach($g in $getlist)
{
   #What it needs to do
   #example
   $g.Value
   #etc.
}
```

How to insert or use the value to store in your JS, i have no idea

Comment: It looks like if I add.Value = "$g" it will pull the value from it just need to figure out how to sort and which collum it should pull from :D Thank you for the help.